# Finding annual growth rate

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

How do I solve the question

> A company’s sales just finished 8 years of consecutive growth, they are now 2x the amount 8 years ago. What is the CAGR?

I guess I should do it like this

$$
K_0 \cdot (1 + r)^8 = 2 \cdot K_0 \Leftrightarrow (1 + r)^8 = 2
$$

but I don't know what to do with the exponent of 8. I guess I could say

$$
(1 + r)^8 = 2 \Leftrightarrow 1 + r =2^\frac{1}{8} \Leftrightarrow r = 2^\frac{1}{8} - 1,
$$

but I have no idea how to calculate $2^\frac{1}{8}$, so I assume there is an easier way.

Is it btw correct to use $2^\frac{1}{8}$ rather than using some logarithmic function (I just can't remember how)?

Comment: Are you allowed to use a calculator ?

Comment: No, it has to be done without calculator

Comment: This is a really challenging problem.